# Setup ng e2e in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have protractor 5.1.2 on my machine. When  I do ng e2e, it download webdriver 2.37. I want to change it to webdriver 2.26. What config should I update to achieve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `ng e2e` will execute `webdriver-manager update` as default, and `np e2e` can't pass down the `--versions.chrom=2.26` to `webdriver-manager update`.

So we can disable the `webdriver-manager update` of `ng e2e` by execute command: `ng e2e --webdriver-update=false` or `ng e2e --wu=false`,  and before execute this command, you have to execute `node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.26` manually to update webdriver to certain version.