# How can I force `ng e2e` to use the latest ChromeDriver

Tags: angular, selenium, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

When I run `ng e2e` I get the following error:

> [16:19:47] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64)
>
> [16:19:47] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64)

The version of Chrome I have installed is "Version 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)". How can I force the Angular End to End tests to use the latest version of the ChromeDriver that supports the latest version of chrome?

Whatever I try, on running `ng e2e` it gets the same version

> [16:19:22] I/update - chromedriver: file exists app-path/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_74.0.3729.6.zip
>
> [16:19:22] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_74.0.3729.6.zip

**Edit**

As a workaround, I can manually upgrade the version of webdriver-manager in the protractor package as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513975/2255594). It's not a long term fix as the change will get wiped out every time I reinstall the node modules.

I don't think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7). That question is specifically about R and RSelenium, and the accepted answer is about generic mismatches with Selenium. My question is specifically about Angular. I haven't installed ChromeDriver or webdriver-manager manually and they are not in my `package.json` file so as far as I'm aware I can't manually select the version.

Can anyone help with solving this issue **within an Angular project**?

Comment: @DebanjanB This isn't a duplicate. That question has nothing to do with Angular, and given that all the packages mentioned in that answer are automatically added to the project I can't manually alter the versions as described.

Comment: The error have nothing to do with angular. Plain and straight error _"session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74"_. Did you have a look at the dup target at-least once?

Comment: I disagree, given that it works if I manually modify the node_modules it looks like the problem is contained within the project. I may be wrong on that, but I cannot see how the linked question helps. Given that I didn't install ChromeDriver, how can I "Downgrade ChromeDriver to ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68 level."

Comment: From Selenium perspective, the linked question points back to the fact that there is a mismatch regarding the version compatibility with the binaries you are using. How to address that would be a angular/framework specific question and have no relation with Selenium per se.

Comment: Agreed, so please re-open my question so someone can actually answer it! The title quite clearly asks 'How' using 'ng', which is the Angular CLI.

Comment: That should be a angular based different question all together.

Comment: Angular command in the title, Angular output in the body, Angular tag. This is an Angular question.

Comment: Your error is from Selenium _"session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74"_ which I have addressed. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: It's not a new requirement. I'll quote my title: 'How can I force `ng e2e` to use the latest ChromeDriver'. Have you answered that? No

Comment: It has been answered recently, I remember the approach was to create a command in package.json to update the chromedriver. Look it up. And there is an answer on github

Comment: For posterity, e2e now automatically updates web drivers, but it can be suppressed by `--webdriver-update=false`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759537/setup-ng-e2e-in-protractor